# Timeout of Continue button in Java security panel in a JWS application

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, java-web-start

I am working on a Java webstart application and am getting the below security alert when launching the application.

JWS plug-in verifies the certificate while launching the application and gives a java security warning.

My doubt is that if I click on the "continue" button after a minute, application crashes with socket timeout exception when I launch it using Java 8 update 66. When I do the same with Java 7 update 76 after even half an hour, application launches successfully.

So, does the timeout of "continue" button feature available in the java security panel is infinite in Java 7 and one minute in Java 8 (OR) does this have anything related to hosting OS - apache modules of SLES11 or SLES12 (in case of my project).

I am not aware of this.

[image]

Comment: `http://server-ip:443` is that really what you want? run http on the usual https port?

Comment: Many thanks for the response.. fvu. I am more bothered about the timeout of "continue" button in java security warning panel.